# Errors while trying to include libvcard in Qt Application

Tags: ubuntu, qt4, vcf-vcard

I am using [libvcard](http://code.google.com/p/libvcard/) in a Qt Application. I installed the library on Ubuntu as instructed in the read me file (i.e. I ran `qmake`, `make`, `sudo make install` on the project file) but when I try to run this code from the website, I get a bunch of errors.

```
   #include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include <vcard/vcard.h>
#include <QtDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Now we can parse it...
    QList<vCard> vcards = vCard::fromFile("/home/ubuntu/Desktop/Contacts.vcf");

    // ...and then we can use it.
    if (!vcards.isEmpty())
    {
        vCard vcard = vcards.takeFirst();

        vCardProperty name_prop = vcard.property(VC_NAME);
        if (name_prop.isValid())
        {
            QStringList values = name_prop.values();

            QString firstname = values.at(vCardProperty::Firstname);
            QString lastname = values.at(vCardProperty::Lastname);

            qDebug()<<firstname<<" "<<lastname;
        }

    }

}
```

**Errors**

> In function main:
>
> /home/ubuntu/Workspace/Qt/cVCardTest-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_1_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Debug/../cVCardTest/main.cpp:8:
>
> error: undefined reference to `vCard::fromFile(QString const&)
>   /home/ubuntu/Workspace/Qt/cVCardTest-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_1_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Debug/../cVCardTest/main.cpp:15:
>
> error: undefined reference to `vCard::property(QString const&, QList<vCardParam> const&, bool) const
>   /home/ubuntu/Workspace/Qt/cVCardTest-build-desktop-Desktop_Qt_4_8_1_for_GCC__Qt_SDK__Debug/../cVCardTest/main.cpp:15: error: undefined reference to`vCard::property(QString const&, QList const&, bool) const'
>   '

I'm not sure what I've done wrong. 
Should I be adding something to the project file in order to use this library?

Comment: you must link with vcard library

Comment: Doesn't that happen automatically? How would I go about this?

Comment: No it doesn't. Probably something like LIBS += vcard in your pro file should do the thing

Comment: You're right. I needed to link the libraries and this http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-2.3/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html  explains how. Please write it as the answer and i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vcard is external library, so linker must know, where to look for used symbols. You need to link with vcard library. In your .pro file add

```
LIBS += vcard
```